# unable to test merge operator of rxjava

Tags: rx-java

I wanted to test `merge` operator using rxjava 1 using:

```
    Observable<Object> o1 = Observable.create((t) -> {

        t.onNext("1");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t.onNext("2");
        t.onCompleted();
    });

    Observable<Object> o2 = Observable.create((t) -> {
        t.onNext("a");
        t.onNext("b");
        t.onCompleted();
    });

    o1.mergeWith(o2).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I expect the output to be: `1ab2` but the actual is `12ab`.

So, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `merge` subscribes to the Observables in a synchronous fashion. And since the first Observable does not explicitly move work to a background thread the body of `create(...)` is also executed synchronously.

This means that when subscribing to `o1` it has to fully complete the body in the `create(...)` call before it subscribes to the next observable.

Explicitly making the observables run in the background using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` would fix the issue.

See: http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html for more about Schedulers

Comment: Note that even subscribeOn may not produce the expected interleaving.